# What does "sticking (sticky) cover" mean in the context of a video game?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, terminology

About the Black Mesa mod:

> "Not For Those Who Want: An all-new experience. It looks new, but it's the same old Half-Life. There's no **sticking cover** or regenerating health here, kids."

<sup>(Kotaku: [The 12 Best Mods For PC Games](http://kotaku.com/5979860/the-12-best-mods-for-pc-games))</sup>

I've already asked this question on [Learn English Online](https://www.englishforums.com/English/StickingCoverMeaning/bhwhkd/post.htm), but they don't seem to know the answer.

Comment: This has little to do with English, but more with game play. My guess would be that "sticking cover" is cover that "sticks" to your player, so your player is hidden even when he moves. It's a cheat in a game.

Comment: @oerkelens I think the stick-to-cover mechanic is part of the basic gameplay of certain games rather than a cheat.  But it's true that it's not a phrase I'd expect most English speakers to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sticking" or "Sticky" cover is a [cover mechanic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_system) where you can cause your avatar press up against a cover object and enter a special mode. When you are behind cover you can take actions you can't take in normal mode, like peeking around what you're hiding behind or taking a "blind" shot where you can't see your target.

It's gamer jargon very specific to shooter games, so I'm not exactly sure it's on-topic here, but I don't know of any other place you might find an answer.  It's not easy to search for that term and get a good answer because most relevant places it's used without being defined.